# MySQL Table doesn't exist when deployed on AWS

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

I deployed my .net core app to aws, but cannot figure out how to make initial migration to create tables.
Is there some equivalent to `dotnet ef migrations add Initial
dotnet ef database update` on aws to create tables when use Code First approach?
My code failing on line:

```
if (context.Record.Any())
            {
                return;   // DB has been seeded
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved by changing MySQL connector from MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore to SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql. All migrations then performed using default commands.

Answer (score 0):

Same as you do it for development.

You have to call `dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()` during application startup (`Configure` method).

You need to create an service scope and then resolve your `DbContext`.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        using (var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>())
        {
            if (dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated())
            {
                // Seed your database if necessary
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Right now this is the only way to create the tables, as Oracle didn't implement neither migration or scaffolding yet.